# How to access specific host and port of an environment's node on jelastic, from another environment?

Tags: networking, environment, jelastic

I have two environments on jelastic 4.7. On one of them I have a Java Stack and a Redis server that need to be kept private without a public IP address. On the other environment, I have a Node.js Stack that have a Public IP.

So, Im searching the docs exhaustively and can't find the answer to the question.

> Can I access the private IP and port of my Redis from the node app?? Every node on Jelastic has a local ip address. Can I access those between environments??

I think it's a simple question. I'm trying to avoid the overhead of creating a public IP Address for Redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I access the private IP and port of my Redis from the node app??
>   Every node on Jelastic has a local ip address. Can I access those
>   between environments??

Yes, you can connect to different nodes of different environments using just a local IP within one hosting provider or its regions (depends on providers setup). Also, you can use [Endpoints](https://docs.jelastic.com/endpoints) in order to connect to local IPs of other providers or to the regions within one provider, if direct connection can't be established.

Besides that, you can use, for example, [CNAME](https://docs.jelastic.com/add-database) of database instead of a local IP.

Comment: Thank you! Using CNAME is the best way. Jelastic is really easy and pragmatic to use :).

Comment: @Marcos Arruda Glad to help you